# transforming between ASTs in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

There are lots of `Haskell` tutorials on parsing sources into an AST, AST rewrites, AST evaluations but not on mapping between two ASTs. Is there a "canonical" way to implement `transformFoo2Bar` in `Haskell`?

```
type FooIdentifier = String
data Foo = Foo FooIdentifier [FooMethod] deriving (Show)
data FooMethod = FooMethod FooIdentifier [FooExpression] deriving (Show)
data FooExpression = FooAB FooIdentifier FooIdentifier | FooZ FooIdentifier deriving (Show)

type BarIdentifier = String
type BarLabel = String
data Bar = Bar BarIdentifier [BarExpression] deriving (Show)
data BarExpression = BarA BarIdentifier BarIdentifier 
                   | BarB BarIdentifier BarIdentifier | BarZ BarIdentifier deriving (Show)

--
-- transformFoo2Bar [Foo "foo" [FooMethod "foo1" [FooAB "a" "b", FooZ "z"], FooMethod "foo2" [FooZ "z"]]]
--         
-- to evaluate to 
--
-- [Bar "foo_foo1" [BarA "a" "b", BarB "a" "b", BarZ "z"], Bar "foo_foo2" [BarZ "z"]] 
--

transformFoo2Bar :: [Foo] -> [Bar]
transformFoo2Bar = undefined
```

Similar to code compilation, but instead of emitting compiled code, keep the result as AST.

Also could some of these mappings be reused as reverse mapping?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question: do you mean to ask if there is a systematic way to transform an AST into another AST whose types are structurally equivalent?

Comment: Just to be clear, I suspect you aren't getting many answers because the question is very broad, and depending on the situation would be answered very differently.  So broad, in fact, that a whole discipline is dedicated to translating stuff to stuff....  functional programming.

Comment: I think you are not looking for AST -> AST here - it seems you are looking on converting between types based on their structure - so what you want is some kind of structural typing or a workaround (if I am right) - there are already questions here on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071603/why-does-haskell-not-have-records-with-structural-typing - and there are some experiments on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shapely-data-0.0 - don't know if there is anything good there though

Comment: To be clear I'm not looking for an automated way, looking to write "proper" code.
In addition, the structures/relationships might be different (maybe the example above is too close to each other ...)
I'm open to suggestions on how to rephrase to get better pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The **highly uncanonical** way to do this is to change the definition of BarExpression around to

```
data BarExpression = BarB BarIdentifier | BarA BarIdentifier BarIdentifier deriving (Show)
```

so that it's not only structurally similar to `FooExpression`, but also has the same runtime representation.

Then you can use [`Unsafe.Coerce.unsafeCoerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce):

```
fe1 = FooA "a"
fe2 = FooB "x" "y"

fm1= FooMethod "meth1" [fe1,fe2]

foo1 = Foo "foo" [fm1]
```

Which allows you to do

```
ghci> unsafeCoerce foo1 :: Bar
Bar "foo" [BarProc "meth1" [BarB "a",BarA "x" "y"]]
```

---

`<font size+=1000 color="red"><blink>`

## **Caveat programmator:**

`</blink></font>`

I don't recommend doing this at all as it will put your eternal soul in peril, will break unexpectedly as soon as you look at it and in very, very bad ways (if you don't swap `BarExpression` this example starts causing segfaults :-) but it works for *this* particular use case.

Alternatively, you could get rid of one of the isomorphic types; is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: Thank you for this pointer. I'm not looking for "automated" conversion, and indeed the two ASTs might not be as close as represented in the question.

Comment: I suspected as much :-) I've got a rough idea for how I would approach it in that case, so could go and post a more constructive and/or canonical answer (it won't fit in this box, not even the outline). Can you update your question with a slighly more representative code sample so I don't have to go and make stuff up? I'm particularly interested in how far corresponding 'levels' (Expressions, Statements, Methods) of the two AST types differ. Do they still have an isomorphism between them or is one strictly more expressive than the other?